# Spring-boot enable compression for non-embedded containers

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, compression, gzip

I want to enable compression to my spring boot app. My initial approach was to use the properties that apply to the spring boot embedded containers.

```
server:
    compression:
        enabled: true
        mime-types: application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
```

However it does not work once I upload the war to a tomcat server. Is there a workaround to achieve compression even when deploying to external containers without any extra (non-spring) configuration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible without any extra configuration. The spring-boot configuration works for the embedded containers.